# OPENSHIFT: I am getting exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, openshift

I am getting exception: `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

We have used Data source connection pooling in JBOSS standalone.xml
we have given max and min size for datasource, but still we are getting connection reset exception. 
we have used openshift to deploy application, can some one help to fix this.
We have executor framework for thread code,

```
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>*******</user-name>
            <password>********</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        </validation>
        <timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>20</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
```

`JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet threw exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

Comment: Are `jboss` and `database` hosted on same machine?

Comment: yes on same machine

Comment: Okay, Are you sure database is up?

Comment: type services.msc in run command or open services app directly and check whether your DB instance is running or not.try restarting it.